# Ford-Fulkerson under constraints, how do I think about setting up a graph?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, data-structures

It’s recently become popular to offload computation from mobile devices (e.g., your Android
smart phone) from the phone to the cloud. The cloud is better at performing computations ef-
ficiently, and often running these computations on your mobile device depletes its battery power
very quickly.

Your device runs programs {1, 2, . . . , p} simultaneously. It can choose to offload any subset of
the programs to the cloud and leave the remaining running on the device. If your device chooses
to offload program i, your device gets a net energy savings of ei ≥ 0. However, there may be a
loss as well; some programs on your phone coordinate with each other (e.g., they share user data
to provide interactive experiences). If one of a pair of programs that coordinates is offloaded and
the other is not offloaded, then there is a cost of coordination that is incurred (cij for the pair of
programs i and j). There’s one more constraint. Some of the programs on your phone contain private data that
you’re really not comfortable offloading to the cloud. For simplicity, let’s think of all of these
programs as a single program, program 1, and program 1 cannot be offloaded. So now, any
program i that coordinates with program 1, if offloaded, receives a benefit of ei but a cost of c1i.

Give a polynomial time algorithm to determine the subset of the remaining programs to offload
to receive the maximum benefit. Assume that energy and coordination costs are measured in
comparable units (i.e., the cost of offloading a subset of the programs is the sum of the ei values for the offloaded programs minus the sum of the cij values such that program i is offloaded and
program j is not).

Comment: Can you share your attempt to solve this question, and what the issue is you’re facing?

Comment: I would run Ford-Fulkerson on with each weight being the the log(-weight) of the items and find the minimum bottleneck but I'm not sure how to handle the rest of the constraints

Comment: Treating this as an undirected, weighted minimum cut problem and using Ford-Fulkerson is one correct approach. It's not clear to me what taking logarithms (of negative numbers?) is meant to do